# Canonical url being linked on Facebook rather than real URL. Dynamic OpenGraph tags coming up empty

Tags: php, facebook, tags, hyperlink, facebook-opengraph

My website is a jobs website If I share a job at the moment the url could be for example

http://jobs.com/jobs/show-job/143/Jobit-flyers-put-up/Other/

But facebook with try to scrape http://jobs.com/jobs/show-job/ because that is the canonical url.

This really sucks when someone posts it on facebook because all the OpenGraph tags are empty so the link gets the wrong thumbnail and blank information. Who knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed!

Inside the header of the dynamic page you are creating simply user the meta og tag

```
 <meta property="og:url" content="<?php get_current_url(); ?>" >
```

Comment: Sorry to comment on your answer.. your answer is correct but i got an issue related to Facebook cache. We all know that facebook cached all the content so the question is: How to refresh cache for each url if a page has more than 1 url? I will be grateful for Any help.

Comment: @ShailParas I recommend redirecting one URL to the other - it is bad practice for the same content to show on two URLs as it can hurt your search engine visibility among other issues. 

Oh also when you fetch a URL with the Facebook debugger it clears the cached version. So if you really want to clear both urls, just submit them both to the debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I looked for it but i'm not getting any idea how to do that so Can you please tell me how can i make this work - `redirecting one URL to the other`.

Comment: @ShailParas Redirection is made by sending a 301 or 302 status code back to the client with the new address to go to.


In your code, when you receive the request, you can check what URL the client used to get there, and if it is not the URL you want them to have used you can then send the redirect message back and it will take them to the correct URL.

Do some research using Google on status codes and also "redirection PHP" - if you are actually writing in PHP. Or if you are using a framework search "redirection <framework>".

Answer (score 4):

Canonical URL is the URL that represent your OpenGraph object and this is intended to work that way!

You can see the [answer I gave to similar question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/10025878/155033) for more details.

Comment: Hi Juicy Scripter, I appreciate the reponse but that link is not very helpful. I am not interested in likes, I am interested in users being able to link a job on my website and the link working. I would also like facebook to be able to get the relevant information from the job and a relevant picture. Right now it gets empty strings and a picture from the job right in the sidebar.

Comment: http://jobit.co.nz/jobs/show-job/143/Jobit-flyers-put-up-around-Auckland/Other/

This is a url of my site. If you go to facebook debugger and fetch it it says:

Response Code: 206
Fetched URL: http://jobit.co.nz/jobs/show-job/143/Jobit-flyers-put-up-around-Auckland/Other/
Canonical URL: http://jobit.co.nz/jobs/show-job/

So it is trying to pull data from the canonical link, but this is useless as it has nothing to do with the job linking.

Comment: @JoshuaDean, `http://jobit.co.nz/jobs/show-job/143/Jobit-flyers-put-up-around-Auckland/Other/` should have itself as `og:url` property not unrelated URL!

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use the og:type of "website" if you are publishing an "article".

For example:

- If you said THIS http://jobs.com/show-job/
- is og:type = website

Then you have told facebook that this:

- http://jobs.com/jobs/show-job/143/Jobit-flyers-put-up/Other/
- is canonical for show-job/

Simply put: use the following:

- og:type = website => http://jobs.com/
- og:type = article => http://jobs.com/show-job/
- og:type = article => http://jobs.com/jobs/show-job/143/Jobit-flyers-put-up/Other/

More information here:
https://ogp.me/#type_article